# A question about Hadamard matrices

Tags: matrices

Is it possible to find a matrix $A$ such that:
$$\exp(A)+\exp(A^{-1})=H_2$$ with $A$ a $2\times 2$ matrix and $H_2$ a Hadamard matrix?
The result can be extended to every Hadamard matrix $H_N$ with $N$ power of two?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have no idea. But how does this problem arise? I am curious.

Comment: I found it on a paper of theoretical physics about superstrings.

Comment: Hint: Try to use $A=a_0I+{\bf a}\cdot{\bf \sigma}$ with $\sigma_i$ Pauli matrices.

Comment: Is $A$ supposed to be real or complex?

Comment: @Joriki: $A$ can be complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $D=\left( \matrix {\sqrt{2}& 0\\0& -\sqrt{2}} \right)$
,

$H_2=PD P^{-1}$, where $P=\left( \matrix {1+\sqrt{2}& 1-\sqrt{2}\\1& 1} \right)$.

$x=\frac{i\pi}{4} \implies e^x+e^{-x}=\sqrt{2}$

$x=\frac{3i\pi}{4} \implies e^x+e^{-x}=-\sqrt{2}$.

Let $E=\left( \matrix {\frac{i\pi}{4}& 0\\0&\frac{3i\pi}{4} } \right) $,

then $A=PEP^{-1}$ is such that $H_2=e^A+e^{-A}$.

$H_{2^n}=(\underbrace{P \otimes P\otimes ...\otimes P}_n)(\underbrace{D \otimes D\otimes ...\otimes D}_n)(\underbrace{P^{-1} \otimes...\otimes P^{-1}}_n)$,
because $H_{2^n}=\underbrace{H \otimes ... \otimes H}_{n}$.

$\underbrace {D \otimes ... \otimes D}_n$ is a diagonal matrix.

For all $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^*$, $x$ exists such that $e^x+e^{-x}=\lambda$.

Let $F$, a diagonal matrix, such that $e^F+e^{-F}=D \otimes ... \otimes D$, then $C=(P \otimes P\otimes ...\otimes P)F(P^{-1} \otimes...\otimes P^{-1})$ is such that $e^C+e^{-C}=H_{2^n}$

Comment: $A^{-1}$ isn't $-A$

Comment: And that is why I thought the problem was rather … strange.